# CakePHP AuthComponent login using Ajax without form?

Tags: ajax, json, cakephp, authentication

I want to create an app using CakePHP 2.2 that allows a non-browser client to connect and store/access data. I've been looking at examples for a user to login with this snippet of code in the UserController:

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if($this->Auth->login())
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Passed');
        }
        else
       {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Failed');
        }
    }
}
```

This is done with the browser presenting a form on the browser and user fills in "username" and "password" then click a button to submit. I know that with Javascript and Ajax, you can "serialize" a form and send it to the server, but suppose I don't want to (or cannot) use form and just have the client send two bits of information: "username" and "password", how can I handle this data from the "login" method like above? I know that `Auth->login` takes an optional argument `$user`, but is there a way to get `$user` from the username/password combination so that I can pass that to `Auth->login`? I imagine something like this:

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if($this->Auth->login())
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Passed');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Failed');
        }
    }
    else if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
    {
        $tmpUser = getUser ('username', 'password'); // ????? ===> Whatever call is needed here.
        if($this->Auth->login($tmpUser))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Passed');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Failed');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you figured out the best way to do this? What about the session id that is set after logging in?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [AuthComponent :: $ajaxLogin](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#authcomponent-api) property while implementing Auth with Ajax login.
 Besides it, You could try the following code:

```
public function login()
{
if($this->request->is('post'))
{
    if($this->Auth->login())
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Login Passed');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Login Failed');
    }
}
else if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
{
    $tmpUser['User']['username'] = $this->request->params['username'];
    $tmpUser['User']['password'] = $this->request->params['password'];
    if($this->Auth->login($tmpUser))
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Login Passed');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Login Failed');
    }
}
}
```

You can check the response using firebug console.